# How to map the response from backend if there is no attribute to identify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

if we have three line of business response in the details object and backend does not identify the lob how i can write the logic for response mapping

main.ts

```
export function after(this: CGetOrdersDetails, backendResponse: IMakeRequestResponse): IAPIReturn {
    const span = startTracingSpan('get-orders-details', 'after', this.parentSpan);

    let pbmResponse;
    let specialtyResponse;
    let retailResponse;
    if (backendResponse.details.length > 1) {
        pbmResponse = this.isPBMLOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[0] : null;
        specialtyResponse = this.isSPLTYLOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[1] : null;
        retailResponse = this.isRETAILOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[2] : null;
    } else {
        pbmResponse = this.isPBMLOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[0] : null;
        specialtyResponse = this.isSPLTYLOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[0] : null;
        retailResponse = this.isRETAILOBInRequest ? backendResponse.details[0] : null;
    }

    const orders: IOrder[] = handleResponse(pbmResponse, specialtyResponse, retailResponse);

    finishTracingSpanWithResult(span, 200);
    return {
        logMessage: Constants.STATUS_DESCRIPTION.SUCCESS,
        responseData: {
            statusCode: Constants.STATUS_CODES.SUCCESS,
            statusDescription: Constants.STATUS_DESCRIPTION.SUCCESS,
            orders
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: without seeing what you can see, the answer is "with great difficulty"

Comment: exactly, you need a proper predefined standard with the backend.